# Do we really need to branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I'm in my first software engineering class.
It's the first time any of us has worked in a team and used git and github.
In class our teacher told us that you should usually branch off the master, after you finish your new feature, merge it back to the master.
This is what I've been doing.
However the other members of my group are not branching.
They pull from the master on github to their local machine, make edits, finish their feature on their local master, then push to the master on github.

I'm trying to convince them to branch but now that I think about it, i find it more confusing.
I've been told that the purpose of the branch is to make a copy of the code and not worry about ruining the master by accidentally putting unrunnable code.

But isn't their local master really just like a branch itself? As they are making edits, they aren't changing the master on github, so others are free to pull working code from github. Then they merge, similar to a branch.

I'm confused, why should we branch if what they are doing seems to be working?

Thanks!

Comment: In real projects, people collaborate on features, team members review the code of others before it's merged, people work on different features or fixes at the same time, features can last a long time and must thus be saved not just on the developer's machine, etc. etc. All this is made possible with branching and pushng branches to github.

Answer (score 11):

> But isn't their local master really just like a branch itself?

Yes it is!

> I'm confused, why should we branch if what they are doing seems to be working?

This depends on your workflow. What you seem to be describing is this workflow:

Alice makes a branch `alice` that tracks `master` and Bob makes a `bob` branch that also tracks `master`. Alice always commits to `alice` and Bob always commits to `bob`. Then when they are happy with their changes they merge into `master`.

Of course, there is hardly any difference from this and from Alice and Bob working on their local `master` branches!

The problem often comes in when the same person is working on multiple features at the same time. For example

Alice is working on `Feature A` and Bob is working on `Feature B`. Alice is halfway done with `Feature A` and has made a few commits in `alice`. However, `Feature A` is quite hard to implement so Alice decides that she should rather work on `Feature C` and makes a few commits onto `alice`. Bob finished `Feature B` and decides that he would like to tackle `Feature A` and so pulls `alice` into `bob`.

After Bob finishes `Feature A` he would like to merge `bob` into `master`. However, `bob` now contains `Feature A`, `Feature B` and parts of `Feature C`, but `Feature C` is not ready to be merged! It's easy to see that a workflow like this can lead to many confusing merge conflicts.

The trick is that instead of having personal branches one should have *feature* branches. Alice should have a branch for `Feature A` and `Feature C` and Bob should have a branch for `Feature B` and `Feature A`. That way they both can work on different features without tramping on each other's toes.

Comment: ok thank you! I think my group plan on working on one feature at a time and on their own. But now I can see that branching is really important if people work on multiple features at a time with collaboration from other members.

Comment: Creating feature branches may seem overkill when you are starting out but they really save you a lot of future hassles when, because of unforeseen problems, many people have to work on the same feature, or some feature is taking too long to get merged and the developer wants to continue working on other problems.

Comment: Great explanation! I think most people using branches redundantly. This is the only reason why people should use them.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it shorter. the master what you have you in the machine is the local master. You push all the changes to `origin/master` server.

A primary reason why it's not encouraged to work on the `master` branch is several people work on the project and in which one branch needs to be the common base for all those who created the branch.

---

For example, you have the product you want to add Bluetooth module to it, then you create a branch add_blueetooth from master when you did then merge that to master. Another guy is working on wifi he can merge his branch into master. It's just the common CVS workflow, where creating branches leads to parallel work.

---

## What really happens when you clone?

Actually, `git clone` fetches all remote branches it creates one local branch that is the `master`, for you. Just type this command `git branch -a`,

```
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD
```

They are other commands where you can see the remote branches using g`it branch -r`.

You can check the reference created by local branch by manoeuvring to this location. `refs/remotes/origin`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you have a master branch where the code is stable and merged.

Let's say that I have an application that scrapes a website.

I will create a new branch called develop/pulldata. In this branch, I will work on pulling the data. One of my team members could work on applying some logic on the data, so he can create his own branch develop/applylogic.

Once he has a few commits and his code is stable, he can open a pull request to merge his code to master, which you can view in the github UI, to see what code he has changed and decide whether or not you want to merge, or if any changes are required.

Now, after a while, my code is done, I open a pull request to master, so my colleagues can view my code and approve or suggest changes. It's easy to view and everybody in the team knows that master branch is stable. However, other branches do not have to be. They have to be when they are merged to master.